# Compiled Jar keeps throwing: Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext

Tags: firebase, intellij-idea, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to make a small application which first scans a HTML for data and then uploads it to my Firestore. I'm now essentially done with it and when starting it from within IntelliJ IDEA it works just fine. However as soon as I export it in to an artifact it starts throwing the following exception when trying to download/upload from/to Firestore!

I should mention that I'm coding in Koltin/JVM as it is way easier. Since there is no Kotlin Firebase-Admin version I'm just using the Java one which shouldn't be a problem since Kotlin compiles down to Java. If I'm wrong about that please correct me!

```
Nov 27, 2019 6:59:17 PM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$1 uncaughtException
SEVERE: [Channel<1>: (firestore.googleapis.com:443)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find policy 'pick_first'. Make sure its implementation is either registered to LoadBalancerRegistry or included in META-INF/services/io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider from your jar files.
    at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory$AutoConfiguredLoadBalancer.<init>(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:97)
    at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.newLoadBalancer(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:67)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.exitIdleMode(ManagedChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$ChannelTransportProvider$1ExitIdleModeForTransport.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:473)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$ChannelTransportProvider.get(ManagedChannelImpl.java:477)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.startInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:257)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.start(ClientCallImpl.java:190)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1.start(CensusTracingModule.java:394)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1.start(CensusStatsModule.java:695)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.start(ForwardingClientCall.java:32)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor$1.start(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController.startCommon(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:115)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController.start(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:101)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.java:68)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcServerStreamingRequestParamCallable.call(GrpcServerStreamingRequestParamCallable.java:61)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.java:59)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.call(WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:237)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingAttemptCallable.call(ServerStreamingAttemptCallable.java:230)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingAttemptCallable.start(ServerStreamingAttemptCallable.java:193)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingServerStreamingCallable.call(RetryingServerStreamingCallable.java:87)
    at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedServerStreamingCallable.call(TracedServerStreamingCallable.java:76)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:237)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:166)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:178)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.streamRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:474)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.getAll(FirestoreImpl.java:243)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.getAll(FirestoreImpl.java:253)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.getAll(FirestoreImpl.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference.get(DocumentReference.java:354)
    at FirebaseHandler.getLehrer(FirebaseHandler.kt:95)
    at HtmReader.readFile(HtmReader.kt:12)
    at MainView.theStuff(MainView.kt:61)
    at MainView.onDock(MainView.kt:44)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent.callOnDock$tornadofx(Component.kt:700)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent$rootSceneWindowShowingPropertyChangeListener$1.changed(Component.kt:556)
    at tornadofx.UIComponent$rootSceneWindowShowingPropertyChangeListener$1.changed(Component.kt:327)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
    at tornadofx.App.start(App.kt:101)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code which (in this case) downloads stuff is as following:

```
fun getLehrer(): HashMap<String, Any> {
        [...]
        val out = HashMap<String, Any>()

        try {
            val future = firestore.collection("stuff").document("lehrer").get()

            future.await()

            if (future.isDone) {
                [...]
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            println(" ++ cant get lehrer liste")
        }

        [...]
    }
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
val future = firestore.collection("stuff").document("lehrer").get()
```

I have been trying to fix this for days now and literally spend hours googeling and trying different things but nothing has worked for me so far!

I tried:

- randomly adding a LoadBalancer since I wasn't able to find any viable docs
- adding the loadbalancer to my META-INF/services
- I also found something that seemed similar here (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5493) but it talks about a load of stuff I don't use and frankly don't understand

FYI: Weirdly my icon from my resource folder turns into a completely different one in the Jar. Don't ask me why. I couldn't find an answer to that as well, but it isn't such a big issue since I can just replace that in the jar.

Oh and also this is my first question so if I made any mistakes I'm sorry! I probably made some spelling errors as well which I apologize for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey so after googling some more I found some an article listing code snipets from LoadBalancerRegistry (https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/io.grpc.LoadBalancerRegistry) and I scrolled around in it and found this: PickFirstBalancerFactory.init()

So i decided to look for this Factory but couldn't find it, instead I found PickFirstLoadBalancerProvider(). Remembering from randomly going through the autocomplete that in order to register something to LoadBalancerRegistry one would need a Provider.

Long story short I set them both together and added the following to the init section of my class and it works fine now!

`LoadBalancerRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register(PickFirstLoadBalancerProvider())`

Thought I should answer if anyone has the same issue!

FYI: The icon still changes to that weird one. I don't know why or how thats even possible but it works if I replace it in the .jar so I don't really care xD

Comment: Encountered a similar problem and `GrpclbLoadBalancerProvider`  not worked for me. But, `PickFirstLoadBalancerProvider` does!

Comment: `LoadBalancerRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register(new PickFirstLoadBalancerProvider());`